# I want to get an indicator of 1 only when 'sector' changes for the same 'num_emp' from one month to other month and 0 otherwise, using DAX in PowerBI

Tags: powerbi, dax

I have a table like this

| num_emp | sector | month |
| --- | --- | --- |
| 1 | 111 | 4 |
| 2 | 222 | 4 |
| 1 | 111 | 5 |
| 2 | 222 | 5 |
| 1 | 222 | 6 |
| 2 | 222 | 6 |
| 1 | 222 | 7 |
| 2 | 222 | 7 |

I want to add a column where if the sector changes from one month to other, I get 1, otherwise I get 0. Something like this:

| num_emp | sector | month | change |
| --- | --- | --- | --- |
| 1 | 111 | 4 | 0 |
| 2 | 222 | 4 | 0 |
| 1 | 111 | 5 | 0 |
| 2 | 222 | 5 | 0 |
| 1 | 222 | 6 | 1 |
| 2 | 222 | 6 | 0 |
| 1 | 222 | 7 | 0 |
| 2 | 222 | 7 | 0 |

As you can see the employ in month 6 change from sector 111 to 222.

I'm really lost on who to do this

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try something similar to:

```
changePost = 
  var prevRows = FILTER('YourTable', [month] < EARLIER([month]) && [num_emp] = EARLIER([num_emp]))
  var lastRow = TOPN(1, prevRows, [month], DESC)
  var lastSector = CALCULATE(MIN('YourTable'[sector]), lastRow)
  return IF(COALESCE(lastSector, [sector]) <> [sector], 1, 0)


changePre = 
  var postRows = FILTER('YourTable', [month] > EARLIER([month]) && [num_emp] = EARLIER([num_emp]))
  var firstRow = TOPN(1, postRows, [month], ASC)
  var firstSector = CALCULATE(MIN('YourTable'[sector]), firstRow)
  return IF(COALESCE(firstSector, [sector]) <> [sector], 1, 0)
```

[image]

Comment: It works! Now i need another column that puts indicator 1 in the month prior to the change. Basically like this.

num_emp | sector | month | change
:------:|:------:|:-----:|-----:
1 |111 |4 |0
2 |222 |4 |0
1 |111 |5 |1
2 |222 |5 |0
1 |222 |6 |0
2 |222 |6 |0
1 |222 |7 |0
2 |222 |7 |0

As you can see the change occurs in month 6, but i want the indicator one to be in month 5

Comment: Changing the goal post. The previous answer should hopefully given you enough inspiration to achieve that. Just in case, I have included it in the answer above.

Comment: Nice, please help mark the answer as Accepted for the benefit of all (the checkmark under the voting buttons).